# How to Remove Scripts Date Comments from Powershell Generate Database Script?

Tags: sql-server-2012, powershell

I am generating Database Generate scripts with Powershell.
What is the option in Powershell to remove Script dates comment lines?

[Automated Script-generation with Powershell and SMO](http://mazon.com)

```
Object:  Table [dbo].[customer]    Script Date: 9/6/2018 4:40:33 PM 


$Filepath='E:\MyScriptsDirectory' # local directory to save build-scripts to
$DataSource='MyServer' # server name and instance
$Database='MyDatabase'# the database to copy from
# set "Option Explicit" to catch subtle errors
set-psdebug -strict
$ErrorActionPreference = "stop" # you can opt to stagger on, bleeding, if an error occurs
# Load SMO assembly, and if we're running SQL 2008 DLLs load the SMOExtended and SQLWMIManagement libraries
$ms='Microsoft.SqlServer'
$v = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "$ms.SMO")
if ((($v.FullName.Split(','))[1].Split('='))[1].Split('.')[0] -ne '9') {
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("$ms.SMOExtended") | out-null
   }
$My="$ms.Management.Smo" #
$s = new-object ("$My.Server") $DataSource
if ($s.Version -eq  $null ){Throw "Can't find the instance $Datasource"}
$db= $s.Databases[$Database] 
if ($db.name -ne $Database){Throw "Can't find the database '$Database' in $Datasource"};
$transfer = new-object ("$My.Transfer") $db
$CreationScriptOptions = new-object ("$My.ScriptingOptions") 
$CreationScriptOptions.ExtendedProperties= $true # yes, we want these
$CreationScriptOptions.DRIAll= $true # and all the constraints 
$CreationScriptOptions.Indexes= $true # Yup, these would be nice
$CreationScriptOptions.Triggers= $true # This should be included when scripting a database
$CreationScriptOptions.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true # this only goes to the file
$CreationScriptOptions.IncludeHeaders = $true; # of course
$CreationScriptOptions.ToFileOnly = $true #no need of string output as well
$CreationScriptOptions.IncludeIfNotExists = $true # not necessary but it means the script can be more versatile
$CreationScriptOptions.Filename =  "$($FilePath)\$($Database)_Build.sql"; 
$transfer = new-object ("$My.Transfer") $s.Databases[$Database]

$transfer.options=$CreationScriptOptions # tell the transfer object of our preferences
$transfer.ScriptTransfer()
"All done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SMO documentation for ScriptingOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions):

**IncludeHeaders** Gets or sets a Boolean property value that specifies whether the generated script is prefixed with a header that contains information which includes the date and time of generation.

So you should be able change this line of your PowerShell script:

```
$CreationScriptOptions.IncludeHeaders = $true; # of course
```

to

```
$CreationScriptOptions.IncludeHeaders = $false; # of course not
```